# (a bit difficult) finding maximum and minimum maybe using Lagrange's multiplier

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

thanks for reading this first :D

I'm trying to solve the problem

"Finding the maximum and minimum of

$x^2+2y$

under the conditions $x^3+3xy+y^3=5,  y\geq0$"

I would super appriciate your help. Cheers.

Comment: The first step is to check that a $\min$ or $\max$ exist. It is fairly straightforward to show that a $\min$ exists, and a little work shows that the function is unbounded above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm giving you some hint to get proceed. Use Lagrange multiplier.

The two equations will be $ 2x=k(3x^2+3y) $ and $2= k(3x+3y^2)$.  From 1st equation put $k=0$ , you can easily check this holds no good as it demands $2=0$

Next divide those equations. You will get conditions like $y=0$ and $xy=1$. From $y=0$, you will immediately get a value of $x$.

On the equation $x^3+3xy+y^3=5$, put $xy=1$. You get solutions like $x+y=2$. And I'm sure you can proceed thereafter.

Comment: I don't follow your hints. How can you just set $x=0$?

Comment: I am sorry, I had mistakenly placed $x$ in place of $k$. Corrected now. And yes you have to check wheather maximum or minimum value exists.